# NSCoding protocol question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding

I want to add the archiving (NSCoding) protocol to my model class, and then i implement both methods `encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder` and `initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder`. MyModelClass has 2 instance variables (NSString and NSImage), so i use the `encodeObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString*)string` method to encode the object plus the value for particular key. But i keep got the error :

`*** -encodeObject:forKey: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSArchiver encodeObject:forKey:]!`

here's my code for NSCoding methods :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
 [super init];
 mainPath = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"mainPath"] retain];
 icon = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"icon"] retain];

 return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
 NSLog(@"encode with coder is called");
 [coder encodeObject:mainPath forKey:@"mainPath"];
 [coder encodeObject:icon forKey:@"icon"];

}
```

And this is how i call them at my controller class :

```
id object = [assetArray objectAtIndex: [[rows lastObject] intValue]];

 if ([object isKindOfClass:[ItemAssetModel class]])
  NSLog(@"object is correct");
 else
  return NO;

 NSData *data = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: object];
```

if i change the `encodeObject:(id)obj forKey:(NSString*)str` with `encodeObject:(id)obj`, the error is stops, but the result is, the archived data does not copy the instance variable value (cmiiw). Do i miss something on this?

thanks.
hebbian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using NSKeyedArchiver instead of NSArchiver.

Comment: Right, because you're using keyed encoding/decoding methods.

Comment: @Hebbian - This answer solved my problem. You need to mark it as the correct one

Comment: saving as NskeyedArchiever, but still crashing.